# Why doesn't AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI work with AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM?

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that uses the default alarm app to set alarms. When I used `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI` with setting alarms, it actually skipped the intent UI and set the alarm. However, when I use the same skip UI with `ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM`, the default alarm app pops up.

This is the code for setting the alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,"id:"+indexOfNote);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,alarmHour);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES,alarmMin);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and this is the code for dismissing the alarm:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_ALARM_SEARCH_MODE, AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,"id:"+index );
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> im building an app that uses the default alarm app to set alarms

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of alarm clock apps for Android that might honor these `Intent` actions. This includes both pre-installed alarm clock apps and user-installed alarm clock apps. There is no single "default alarm app".

> but when i use the same skip ui with ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM the default alarm app pops up

[`EXTRA_SKIP_UI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_SKIP_UI) is not documented for use with [`ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM). So, what you are seeing is what I would expect.

Comment: how can i delete alarm and skip UI at the same time as in the case of setting alarm ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMagdy: You can't. There is no guarantee that `EXTRA_SKIP_UI` will work for `ACTION_SET_ALARM` either. If you absolutely cannot have a UI, then you will need to implement your own alarm clock functionality, rather than depend on any one of many third-party apps.